# System event notifications are not supported under the current context

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, systemevent

I am getting this error when binding to SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged in a WCF service hosted in IIS:

"System event notifications are not supported under the current context. Server processes, for example, may not support global system event notifications."

```
   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.EnsureSystemEvents(Boolean requireHandle, Boolean throwOnRefusal)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.add_PowerModeChanged(PowerModeChangedEventHandler value)
```

Looking online for some solutions but cannot find any. I am assuming this is an issue related to IIS hosting since the service has some layers of separation from the OS?

Are there any other events I could bind to which would indicate system "suspend" and "resume" states?

Comment: The error message seems quite clear and to the point. So what's the actual question here?

Comment: Is there a way I could bind to system sleep and resume events in WCF services (perhaps not PowerModeChanged, maybe some other event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your exception message is self explanatory.  global system event notifications are not supported here.

I don't know why you want to do this in IIS. But as you want to so, i would suggest you to write a `windows service` and communicate with it using something like `Named Pipes, MSMQ` etc to get such events.

Comment: Good suggestion, I was hoping maybe there was another event I could bind to which indicate "suspend" and "resume" states.

Comment: @vapen i guess this is your only option here. and if it solves your problem you can always mark it as accepted.